# Can I login using something other than a password; i.e. a keypad using GPIO pins?

Tags: password, login

I know with other distributions of Linux you can use fingerprint readers to login instead of using a password.  Is it possible to do this on the Raspberry Pi using like a 4x4 membrane keypad with my own program?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing what you want.

The most straightforward way is to emulate an input device using your keypad. A Python script using `uinput` was already mentioned. There are tools like [`inputattach`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Serial_input_device_to_kernel_input) which do this kind of conversion for popular devices such as old mice/joysticks with UART interface.

The second solution is to introduce an alternative login method. For console logins it is possible to write a custom `login` script which reads the password from the keypad, and configure `getty` to use that script instead of the original `login`, or replace `getty` with a custom script which runs an actual `getty` only after getting a password from the keypad. For GUI logins there is a similar way to login using custom `pam` modules for unusual login devices such as [smart cards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167691/passwordless-login-with-yubikey-5-nfc).

Finally, a less secure but easier to set up solution is to enable autologin, but instantly lock out the user using an autorun / screensaver script. That script would then unlock the screen only after the correct input comes from the keypad.

Answer (score 0):

If your keypad can somehow interface with main input (i.e. do a keyboard's job) and can type keys, it's completely possible.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a USB numpad: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=usb+numpad&t=ffab&ia=products

Comment: Nope, it's just a 4x4 matrix that has a 8 pin female connector. I have it working fine with GPIO pins.

Answer (score 0):

To interface with the main input, you could write a python program using the GPIO and the `uinput` module. This makes it easy to create your own keypads. Install with the command `sudo pip install uinput`. For info on the module, please see [here](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/).